# Chrome extension Options Page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been working on a simple Chrome Extension/Userscript and I have it working completely fine. However, I decided to attempt adding an options page to select a desired option. However, I cannot get it to work...

Here is my options.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Extension Options</title>
</head>

<select id="changeEmotes">
 <option value="twitch">Twitch</option>
 <option value="custom">Only Custom</option>
</select>

<button id="saveData">Save</button>

<script src="options.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My options.js:

```
function saveData()
{   
var test = document.getElementById('changeEmotes').value;
chrome.storage.local.set({
    emoteSetting: test
}, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
    setTimeout(function() {
    status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
});

var emoteSetting = "";
chrome.storage.local.get("emoteSetting", function(result) {
    emoteSetting = result.emoteSetting;
    alert(result.emoteSetting);
});

}

document.getElementById('saveData').addEventListener('click', saveData);
```

and finally, my script.js:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Hitbox Emotes
// @namespace Hitbox Emotes
// @description Allows the use of Twitch emotes on Hitbox.
// @include *.hitbox.tv/*
// @include *.speedrun.tv/*
// @include *.twitch.tv/*
// @icon http://i.imgur.com/fa1Kkku.png
// @version 1.1.8
// @updateURL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GamingTom/11141717/raw/465792.user.js
// @downloadURL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GamingTom/11141717/raw/465792.user.js
// ==/UserScript==

function hitbox_twitch()
{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GamingTom/11142192/raw/emotes.js";
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if(head) head.appendChild(script);
}

function hitbox_custom()
{
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "www.test.com";
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
if(head) head.appendChild(script);
}

function update()
{
    var emoteSetting = "";
chrome.storage.local.get("emoteSetting", function(result) {
    emoteSetting = result.emoteSetting;
    console.log(result.emoteSetting);
            alert(result.emoteSetting);
});

}

update();
```

My script.js usually runs on site load if I do something like "hitbox_twitch();" at the end instead of "update();" and when I do click the save button on the options.html it does alert the correct variable for what I am looking for. However, the alert box does not appear when the site loads and I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined" posted in the console. So in summary, the code works in the options.html but not in the script.js.

If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated, and if you need any more information, please just ask. Many thanks.

-Tom

EDIT:
My manifest file:

```
{
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "contentscript.js" ],
      "matches": [ "*://*.hitbox.tv/*" ]
   } ],
   "description": "Allows the use of Twitch emotes on Hitbox.",
   "options_page": "options.html",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icon128.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Hitbox Emotes",
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "1.1.8",
   "web_accessible_resources": [ "script.js" ],
   "permissions": ["storage"]
}
```

Comment: Did you add the `"storage"` permission to your manifest file?

Comment: Yep, I added `"permissions": ["storage"]` to the end.

Comment: Did you reload the extension after adding the permission? Does the code run in a content script (if you're not sure, use https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/tree/master/scriptTagContext and tell me whether the problem goes away)

Comment: I have this: http://pastebin.com/z15zRKtZ content script which puts everything in the script.js into the site head.

Comment: That method puts the code in the page's context. It no longer runs in the extension's execution context, so you cannot use extension APIs. You should run the code in the content script. I suggest to put the emoticons in your extension instead of Github. If you're not sure what I mean by "execution environment", read https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment.